# Flash Plugin - How to disable automatic updates on a computer that is offline?

Tags: internet, automatic-updates, flash

<sub>**Note:** This is only marginally related to [another question I asked earlier about Adobe Reader](https://serverfault.com/questions/49377/adobe-reader-how-to-disable-automatic-updates-on-a-computer-that-is-offline), and only because I am trying to achieve the same basic effect for a *different piece of software* on the same machine.</sub>

I have a computer that is currently at a location that does not yet have internet access.  I just performed a clean install of XP SP3, and am in the process of installing some basic software.  Among these is the Flash Player plugin for Firefox.

I want to disable automatic updates to the Flash Player plugin.  Now, on an internet connected computer, I would go [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager05.html) and uncheck "Notify me when an update to Adobe Flash Player is available."

Without internet access, how can I achieve the same result?

What is the registry key that I need to change to prevent flash player from checking for or installing any automatic updates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Adobe Flash Player Administration Guide for Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/flash_player_admin_guide.pdf) , chapter 3

From: http://www.asvguy.com/2004/04/configuring_the.html

Comment: Thanks.  In summary, it looks like (on XP anyway) I need to create a file "C:WINNT\System32\mms.cfg" that contains a line "AutoUpdateDisable=1" to do what I want.  The updated link for the documentation is http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/15/flex_docs_en/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Flex_Documentation&file=00000941.htm

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my comment two days ago :P

Answer (score 1):

The setting seems to be kept somewhere in %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\settings.sol which appears to also contain all per-domain settings and who knows what else. Couldn't guarantee what'd happen if you copied it from one machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Windows much in a while but Firefox will check for updates of addon's itself too - if the flash plugin has any add-on hooks (I'm not sure it does as it doesn't on OS X or Linux) - but other addons & firefox itself will also periodically check for updates. All of this can be disabled and/or have timing changed in Firefox's Preferences > Advanced > Updates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an official page from Adobe: [Managing Flash Player auto-update](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/1/flex_docs/00001060.htm). Basically it says you need to create the file `C:\WINDOWS\System32\mms.cfg` with the following text in it:

```
AutoUpdateDisable=1
```